# Assign active class based on current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to assign the `active` class to my student if he is on a student page.

```
<p><%= link_to student.name, student_url(student.student_id), 
      class: ('active' if current_page? ) %></p>
```

Below is my url where i am navigating.

```
https://localhost:3000/student/19
```

How would i use the Rails helper `current_page?` to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current_page? method needs to have parameters passed into the method. For example:

```
<p><%= link_to student.name, student_url(student.student_id), 
  class: ('active' if current_page?(student_path(student.student_id)) ) %></p>
```

student_path(student.student_id) should return /student/19 while the current_page?(student_path(student.student_id)) should return true.

I'm not sure if the structure of your if is going to work. Sometimes I just a ternary for these situations:

```
<p><%= link_to student.name, student_url(student.student_id), 
  class: (current_page?(student_path(student.student_id)) ? 'active' : '' ) %></p>
```

You can get the idea. Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I am using student_url and it seems not work. should we use student_path or can we use student_url too in current_page helper.

Comment: student_path will just render the "/student/19" instead of "http://localhost:3000/student/19".

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F <--- some documentation about the current_page? method.